# Unable to write Message in DLQ

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to send error messages from Lambda to DLQ. I can see error messages in cloudwatch logs but unable to see any entry in DLQ. I followed below steps-

1- Created Lambda Functions.

2- Added API gateway as trigger.

3- Created a queue in SQS as standard.

4- Assigned SQS full access policy to Lambda Role.

5- Configured Asynchronous invocation in Lambda Function and defined my queue which i created in step 3.

Do I need to do anything additional on API gateway or Lambda.

Comment: I've done the same and unfortunately errors are not delivered to SQS dead letter queue.